# Group and Sum with a linear distribution MongoDb Aggregation Framework

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have to group by the values of myArray and sum the total with a linear attribution, it's mean for the both documents we should make a linear distribution of the total value on all the values :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8618"),
    "total" : 5.8,
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        },
        {
            "value" : "a"
        },
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }
    ]
}


/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8619"),
    "total" : 4.5,
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : c"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

in this example we have to get :

```
"a" -> 4/6 * 5.8 + 1/3 * 4.5 / "b" -> 1/6*5.8 +0*4.5 / "c" -> 1/6*5.8 + 2/3*4.5
```

The result have to be like this :

```
 [
      {
        "_id": "a",
        "linear_total": 4/6 * 5.8 + 1/3 * 4.5
      },
      {
        "_id": "b",
        "linear_total": 1/6*5.8 +0*4.5
      },
      {
        "_id": "c",
        "linear_total": 1/6*5.8 + 2/3*4.5
      }
    ]
```

I don't know if this is an available features in aggregation that can calculate the distribution of a value in array, so I can easily multiply by the total and sum .. or you have any ideas of how to make it. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    total: 1,
    myArray: 1,
    arraySize: { $size: "$myArray"} // count the size of your array
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$myArray" // flatten your array
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {id: "$_id", value: "$myArray.value"},
    total: { $first: "$total"},
    myArray: { $first: "$myArray"},
    arraySize: { $first: "$arraySize" },
    countVal: { $sum: 1} // count the occurrence of value out of total array size in each document  
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    divmulti: { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": ["$countVal","$arraySize"] }, "$total" ] } 
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.value", // group by value
    "linear_total": { $sum: "$divmulti" } // and some the results
  }
}
])
```

With this example, you would get this as result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "c", 
    "linear_total" : 3.966666666666667
}
{ 
    "_id" : "b", 
    "linear_total" : 0.9666666666666666
}
{ 
    "_id" : "a", 
    "linear_total" : 5.366666666666666
}
```

Comment: +1 @Alex.P, Can you help for the same logic but with a different distribution, it will be something like 40% of total is given to the first and 40% for the last and the rest (20%)  is shared with the others in the middle. I tried something with same logic but I found some difficults

Comment: @Dr.Mza by first you mean `_id: a` last `_id: b` and middle `_id: c` ? Can you explain it a little?

Comment: P I make a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167667/group-and-sum-according-to-the-position-percentage-mongodb-aggregation
Thank you for helping boss

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation.

`$addFields` to add extra field to keep the size of "myArray".
`$unwind` "myArray"
`$group` to count the occurrence for each value within each "myArray"
`$group` on "value" to calculate linear total.

```
db.col.aggregate([
{"$addFields":{
  "tot":{"$size":"$myArray"}
}},
{"$unwind":"$myArray"},
{"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "id":"$_id",
    "value":"$myArray.value"
  },
  "total":{"$first":"$total"},
  "tot":{"$first":"$tot"},
  "occ":{"$sum":1}
}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id.value",
  "linear_total":{"$sum":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":["$occ","$tot"]},"$total"]}}
}},
{"$sort":{"_id":1}}])
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, your answer is clean and correct and have the same logic as Alex. thank you so much for helping me