# Group and Sum according to the position percentage MongoDb Aggregation

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have to group by the values of myArray and sum the total with a different attribution, it's mean for example for this documents we should make a distribution to make 40% of total for the the first value of the array and 40%(2/5) of total for the last and 20%(1/5) for others shared equitaly :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8618"),
    "total" : 5.8,
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"  2/5 (40%)
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b   1/20 (20% /4)
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "a" 1/20 (20% / 4)
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"  1/20 (20% / 4)
        },
        {
            "value" : "a"  1/20 (20% / 4)
        },
        {
            "value" : "a" 2/5 (40%)
        }
    ]
}



/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8619"),
    "total" : 4.5,
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a" 2/5 (40%)
        }, 
        {
            "value" : c"  1/5 (20%)
        }, 
        { 
            "value" : "c" 2/5 (40%)
        }
    ]
}
```

in this example we have to get :

```
"a" -> 2/5 * 5.8 + 2/5 * 5.8 + 1/10*5.8 + 1/10*5.8  2/5 * 4.5 / "b" -> 1/20*5.8 +0*4.5 / "c" -> 1/20*5.8 + 1/5*4.5 + 2/5*4.5
```

The result have to be like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "a",
    "total": 2/5 * 5.8 + 2/5 * 5.8 + 1/10*5.8 + 1/10*5.8  2/5 * 4.5
  },
  {
    "_id": "b",
    "total": 1/20*5.8
  },
  {
    "_id": "c",
    "linear_total": 1/20*5.8 + 1/5*4.5 + 2/5*4.5
  }
]
```

I have to group by Path.value and sum the correspondant values in each array with this logic

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Veeram can I get your help ?

Comment: @Alex P. what do you think ?

Comment: @Alex P. 2/5 is 40%..  for the first and the last we take 40% of total and for the rest we give 20% of the all .

Comment: Example an array of a,b,c,a,d : with a total = x / the result should be : a->total : 40%*x+20%/3 *a and b->total : 20% /3 and c->total : 20% / 3 and d-> 40%

Comment: @AlexP. we distribute the total value into all the elements of the array in the way that the first get 40% of total and the last 40% and the others the rest shared equitaly

Comment: @AlexP. it's like the previous example but here we have to group by value and sum the total correspondant for each value in the way that the value get 2/5 of the total in is in the first or the last in the array and 1/5 of total if it's in middle, and the case when we have just 2 elements in arrays it's will take 50% 50%

Comment: @AlexP. no problem thank you so much for your help I'm trying now to solve it. I hope just that you understand well the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 pipeline.

Assign weights based on element position.

`$switch` case to provide different weights based on size of array.

```
db.col.aggregate([{"$addFields":{
  "myArray":{
    "$switch":{
      "branches":[{
        "case":{"$gt":[{"$size":"$myArray"},2]},
        "then":{"$concatArrays":[
            [{"value":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray.value",0]},"weight":{"$divide":[2,5]}}],
            {"$map":{
              "input":{"$slice":["$myArray",1,{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$myArray"},2]}]},
              "as":"val",
              "in":{"value":"$$val.value","weight":{"$divide": [{"$divide":[1,5]},{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$myArray"},2]} ]}}
            }},
            [{"value":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray.value",-1]},"weight":{"$divide":[2,5]}}]
          ]}
       },
       {
        "case":{"$eq":[{"$size":"$myArray"},2]},
        "then":{"$concatArrays":[
          [{"value":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray.value",0]},"weight":{"$divide":[1,2]}}],
          [{"value":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray.value",-1]},"weight":{"$divide":[1,2]}}]
        ]}
       }],
    "default":{"$concatArrays":[
      [{"value":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray.value",0]},"weight":1}],
    ]}}
  }
}},
{"$unwind":"$myArray"},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$myArray.value",
  "linear_total":{"$sum":{"$multiply":["$myArray.weight","$total"]}}
}},
{"$sort":{"_id":1}}])
```

Comment: thank you boss, I'm trying now to verify the results I think your logic it's correct

Comment: Cool. Couldn't approve your last edit as I didn't see Path variable in the question. `{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$Path"},2]} `

Comment: `$Path` is `$myArray` in the example

Comment: now the big deal is to make it with java aggregations

Comment: did you ever use java for this type of pipelines ? I don't like to embed a lot of DBObjects to build this pipeline

Comment: I did it with `JSON.parse(..)` and I cast the result Object to `List<DBObject>` and I aggregate the collection with it. It's working now. But I'm asking if there is any cons for this trick in memory-built or something else comparing to Aggregations class in Java ?

Comment: do you use spring-mongodb ? or mongo-java-driver directly ? It depends. I'm assuming you mean spring-mongodb. You can also use Aggregation methods to write your aggregation to certain extent. Not sure if you can write all of it. Coming to problems you lose all the type safety checks when you use DBObject directly and also spring auto maps DBObject to your POJO.